# what is the differece between *p=var and p = var in pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I was learning pointers in c where i saw these examples and i become confused about pointers,

example1:

```
int i;
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *p = a;     // same as int*p = &a[0]
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *p);
        p++;
    }
```

> output: 12345

example2:

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
int *p;
p = arr;
int i ;
for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    printf("%d",*p);
    p++;
}
```

> output:122

so what is the difference between *p=arr and p=arr in pointers ? and when i should use the first one and the second one ?

Comment: `int *p = a;` is completely equivalent to `int *p; p = a;` But it's NOT equivalent to `int *p; *p = a;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, i know that , but what is the difference between them ?

Comment: (1) and (2) are equivalent, they let you change the pointer itself (that is, choose what variable it points to). (3) lets you assign to the variable the pointer currently points to. It should be explained well in any half-decent C++ book...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think that the OP is confused by the `*` in pointer definition

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Thanks alot , but the third statement i dont understand it , can you explain it please .

Answer (score 1):

In C programming language,in some cases array **name** can ***decay to pointer*** to the first element in the `array`.Array name in your case is `a` in the first code snippet and `arr` in the second code snippet, can *decays* to pointer(address) to the array start in memory! So we can look at the array name somehow like an *`"alias"`* for the first element, `&arr[0]` !

**Just to be clear, arrays are not pointers!**
e.g. An array is a single, pre allocated chunk of contiguous elements (all of the same type), fixed in size and location, and A pointer is a place in memory that keeps address of another place inside.

so when we declare `int *p = a;` we are declaring a new pointer of type `int*` and initialize it to point to the first element in the array `a`. we also can do it like this (its the same):
`int* p = &a[0]; //point to the first element in the array a`

if you want to see on the screen, that this is correct, you can use the `conversion format specifier %p` inorder to print addresses:
see below:

`printf("%p == %p \n",(void*)a,(void*)&a[0]);`

you can read this [web_page](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-pointer-to-array-example/). they have a good examples.

for further reading about *`Relationship Between Arrays and Pointers`* please refare to this websites:
 1. [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

I think no answer here is actually addressing your confusion: `*p` vs `p`.

What you need to understand is that `*` has two completely different meanings depending on where it is used:

- when it is used as part of the type specifier it denoted the pointer type. For instance when you declare a variable named `p` of type pointer to int: `int* p`. Here `*` is part of the type of the declaration and means pointer type.
- when it is used in an expression it is the dereference operator. It's an unary operator accepting a pointer operand and it accesses the object found at that address. For instance in something like `*p = 24`.

You say what is the difference between `*p = a` and `p = a` but that is a wrong comparison  for your example because `*p` from your **doesn't stand on its own**. Here is what I mean:

```
   int * p = 24;
// ^~~~~ ^ ^----
// type  |  initializer
         |
         name of the variable
```

In the above:

- `int *` is the type of the symbol declared.
- `p` is the name of the variable declared
- `= 24` is the initializer for the variable

So you see talking about `* p` here makes no sense.

Talking about `*p` makes sense when `*` is the dereference operator. For instance:

```
int a = 11;
int b = 17;

int* p = &a; // declare the variable named p of type `int*`
             // and assign `&a` (aka the address of a) to it
             // p points to the object a

*p = 3; // assign 3 to the object found in memory at the address denoted by p
        // this effectively changes `a` to 3

p = &b;  // assign the address of b to p. p is now a pointer pointing to the object b

*p = 24; // assign 3 to the object found in memory at the address denoted by p
         // this effectively changes `b` to 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you ***define*** pointer `p` and initialize it. The `*` is used to show compiler that the `p` is the pointer and it does not dereference the `p`

```
int *p = a;
```

In this case you assign the pointer `p` with the reference to array (in this case to array `arr` as in the code in your question)

```
p = arr;
```

In the last statement you dereference the pointer `p` and the `*` is used to dereference the pointer

```
printf("%d",*p);
```

Comment: @P_J_ Thanks , but in fact i misunderstand your words , all i want is , what is the difference between int *p = a ; and int *p p=a ;

Comment: @Test065 I have explained it. It is the same. The third one is different

Answer (score 0):

in the first example: 
`a` points to the first integer in the array (the type of a is `int *`)
`int *p = a;` here we define a pointer `p` to points where `a` points to.

the same in second example:
we first define a pointer `p` and the we assign it to points where `a` points to.

Comment: Thanks , you mean both examples are the same  ?

Comment: yes. if my answer helped you please vote me up please.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable which contains the address in memory of another variable. We can have a pointer to any variable type. 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-*p-**p-***p-in-pointers

Comment: True, but not responsive to the question.  It seems clear that the OP already knows what a pointer is.

Comment: Additionally, your link is broken, and the text consists entirely of a quotation (with attribution).

Answer (score 0):

The first example is an *initialization* - you are setting the value of `p` as you declare it.  The second example is an *assignment* - you are setting the value of `p` as a standalone operation.

Both statements have the same effect in that they assign the address of the first element of `a` to `p`.

The unary `*` in a declaration simply means the thing being declared has pointer type - it’s not doing a dereference operation.  The initializer is assigning a value to `p`, not to `*p`.